# unsigned integer variable displays as 0 when some alphabets are given as input

Tags: c++, c++17

I am newbie to C++ and, while going through the literature and tutorials, I came across an anomaly for the given code:

```cpp
//Include the iostream, which is used to include libraries for the i/o operation for the console

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (void){

    unsigned int var1(0xFF);//Direct initialization of the variable
    //Capture the value from the cin
    cout << "Initial value is " << var1 << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the value\n";
    cin >> var1;
    //Display the value
    cout << "Enterd value is " << var1 << endl;
    cout << "*******END******" << endl;
    //Returning '0' for successful app execution
    return 0;
}
```

When input is given as 'A' the output is displays as '0' and that's where the confusion exists. Can somebody explain why this is?

Comment: What do you expect? 'A' is not a number. Check if cin failed after >>.

Comment: Correct, however it will be an ascii somwhere a number itself then I was expecting it will print the ASCII number.

Comment: Your expectation does not take place in the reality. If you want to get ASCII code then read char, not unsigned int.

Comment: If you want to take a character as input and print out its ASCII value, you should ask that in the question instead...

Comment: @delve123, Consider that in order for that to be consistent, it would have to store the integral value of `'0'` (typically 48) when the user enters 0, which is completely unexpected.

Comment: @S.M. Evidently, that's the very reason I asked for help, however can you elaborate the reason for the same ? Thanks

Comment: If you want to input a number, then typing a non-number should be considered a user error. Any other behaviour is not acceptable.

Comment: Input and output are overloaded so numbers are input and output as numbers and characters are input and output as characters. If you want to convert a character to a number input a char c1; cin >> c1; then convert var1 = c1; then cout << var1 will output the value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the ASCII value for the inputted character you can use this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char input;
    cout << "Please enter a character: ";
    cin >> input;
    
    if (cin.fail())
        cout << "Parsing error.";
    else
        cout << "Its ASCII value is " << int(input) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The key point here is the type cast at the line where `cout` prints the resulted ASCII value. If you would use just `input` you would get the character value instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect just hexadecimals, try: cin >> hex >> var1;

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet, When you try to give a character like 'a' as input for the declared integer variable `var1`, it takes zero(0) so there happens is actually a character size is 1 byte and integer size is 2 byte. So that it behaves abnormally and results in infinite loop cases.

```
unsigned int var1(0xFF);//Direct initialization of the variable
//Capture the value from the cin
cout << "Initial value is " << var1 << endl;
cout << "Please enter the value\n";
cin >> var1;
```

**For why zero assigning?**

For example,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
    for (char a = 0; a <= 225; a++)
    cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

a is declared as char datatype. Here the loop is working from 0 to 225. So, it must print from 0 to 225, then stop. But it will generate an infinite loop. The reason is  valid range of character datatype is -128 to 127. When ‘a’ become 128 through a++, the range is exceeded and as a result the first number from negative side of the range (i.e. -128) gets assigned to a. As a result of this ‘a’ will never reach at point 225. so it will print the infinite series of character.

This range exceed criteria is the reason for the zero(0). It also has a concept **underflow**.

```
Two things can happen when we give value to datatype which it can't handle:
   
    **Underflow** occurs when we try to store a value that is outside the range of the type that's lower that range for underflow.
   
    **Overflow** occurs when we try to store a value that is outside the range of the type that's higher that range for overflow
    or is also a phenomenon where operations on 2 variable of same datatype exceeds the maximum value the data type can have.
```